# Error: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView2'. Remove one definition.?

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview

when I write this query (using LINQ):

```
        Dim hw22 = From hw In db.HWs _
                   Select hw
```

then:

```
        GridView2.DataSource = hw22
        GridView2.DataBind()
```

this error occurs: http://www.rofof.com/img2/6hscmu7.gif

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to remove it in markup then do this:

```
GridView2.DataSourceID = ""
GridView2.DataSource = hw22
GridView2.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably have the DataSourceId defined in markup code

Comment: remove the DataSourceId definition from the .aspx file

Comment: how can I rem you hove it ? can you help me please ?